# "TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerBlocks' of null" for InnerBlocks in Gutenberg

Tags: javascript, wordpress, reactjs, wordpress-gutenberg

I have recently asked a question about the same [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56132541/cannot-read-property-geteditedpostattribute-of-undefined-for-innerblocks-in). There I have found the issue myself. But unfortunately, I got a new error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerBlocks' of null
    at InnerBlocks.synchronizeBlocksWithTemplate (script.build.js?ver=1:149405)
    at InnerBlocks.componentDidMount (script.build.js?ver=1:149366)
    at zc (react-dom.min.js?ver=16.6.3:146)
    at wc (react-dom.min.js?ver=16.6.3:138)
    at fa (react-dom.min.js?ver=16.6.3:137)
    at ng (react-dom.min.js?ver=16.6.3:149)
    at Se (react-dom.min.js?ver=16.6.3:40)
```

So I have tried it with the same code but I don't get it to work:

```
const {registerBlockType} = wp.blocks;
const {InspectorControls, RichText, MediaUpload} = wp.editor;

import {TextControl} from '@wordpress/components';

import {InnerBlocks} from '@wordpress/editor';

let blockStyle = {
    marginTop: "25px",
    marginBottom: "25px;"
};

registerBlockType('myself/test-component', {
    title: 'Test component',
    icon: 'editor-insertmore',
    category: 'common',
    attributes: {
        title: {
            type: 'string'
        }
    },

    edit(props) {
        const {setAttributes, attributes} = props;

        function setTitle(changes) {
            setAttributes({
                title: changes
            })
        }

        return (
            <div style={blockStyle}>
                <TextControl
                    placeholder="Titel"
                    value={attributes.title}
                    onChange={setTitle}
                />
                <InnerBlocks
                    templateLock={false}
                    renderAppender={(
                        () => <InnerBlocks.ButtonBlockAppender/>
                    )}
                />
            </div>
        )
    },

    save(props) {
        const {attributes, className} = props;

        return (
            <div style={blockStyle}>
                <InnerBlocks.Content/>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Then I have checked the built script.js file which is embedded as a plugin. There we have the following situation that the `this.props.block` is `null`.

```
key: "componentDidMount",
value: function componentDidMount() {
  var innerBlocks = this.props.block.innerBlocks; // only synchronize innerBlocks with template if innerBlocks are empty or a locking all exists

  if (innerBlocks.length === 0 || this.getTemplateLock() === 'all') {
    this.synchronizeBlocksWithTemplate();
  }

  if (this.state.templateInProcess) {
    this.setState({
      templateInProcess: false
    });
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

The variable `this.props` has the following variables:

[image: Variables of this.props]

Does anyone facing the same problem or have a workaround for that?

Comment: I don't see where you're passing the 'block' prop.

Comment: @rrd I have tried to set the attribute to the InnerBlocks component, but it hasn't worked. It looks like an internal `prop` after the build process. I have updated my question with a screenshot, showing the `this.props` object.

Comment: Well this.props.block appears to be null, so innerBlocks is never going to be there. That's why you're getting the error - in fact the error itself tells you the same.

Comment: @rrd, thats correct, I noticed that also already. But why is this `block` `null`. I have no option to define that object except for these attributes as described on this site: https://www.ibenic.com/enable-inner-blocks-gutenberg/#gist91608525

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Again, I solved my own question. The problem, in the end, is for me not clear, but it worked.

What I've done now is to simply use the `wp.editor` as the import instance for the `InnerBlocks` component. With that, it loads now the complete InnerBlocks Editor and I am now able to add custom blocks in that.

```
const {registerBlockType} = wp.blocks;
const {InspectorControls, RichText, InnerBlocks} = wp.editor; //Imported the InnerBlocks from this source.

import {CheckboxControl, TextControl} from '@wordpress/components';

// Removed this line
// import {InnerBlocks} from "@wordpress/editor";
```